# After installing opencv3.3,import cv2 gives "libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file"

Tags: python, opencv

I have cleaned opencv 3.1 from ubuntu 16.04

```
run "sudo cat install_manifest.txt | xargs echo sudo rm | sh" 
and rm cv2.so from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so,
```

upgrade to 3.3 manually(cmake/make/make install) then

```
sudo ldconfig
run:ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
```

got

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc85de1000)
    libopencv_hdf.so.3.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so.3.3 (0x00007f605d4bd000)
    libopencv_reg.so.3.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so.3.3 (0x00007f605cf8a000)
```

but under ipython

```
  import cv2
```

gives me:

```
ImportError: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously,it is trying to use previous version,and it seems something has been cached,am I right?How to solve this problem?

Comment: Find out which python version is ipython using, and where is it located.

Comment: @Zinarod,IPython 5.4.1 is using Python 2.7.12 which is in /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue.Corrected now.
You can check the module path in python :

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This will show you were python is trying to catch the cv2.so when doing import cv2. 
Then check in all the folders mentioned in the print result if an old cv2.so or a symlink is not remaining, so taking place of the new one you try to use.

It could be simply in the '.' current folder as '.' is part of the syspath.